# How to execute PL/SQL procedures from DataGrip

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

I am new to DataGrip IDE and I have some problems understanding it.

I am able to create a procedure in DataGrip and the output in the terminal shows procedure created, but when I want to execute the procedure with command `execute p2` or `exec p2` (`p2` is procedure name) DataGrip shows error 'invalid SQL statement' or 'nothing to run'.

Comment: I haven't used Datagrip, but `execute` and its abbreviations are part of SQL\*Plus, not SQL or PL/SQL themselves, so maybe that will only work if you tell it to treat the command as a SQL\*Plus style script. Alternatively, what about `call(p2)` ('call' is part of SQL) or `begin p2; end;` (a valid PL/SQL block).

Comment: Just to add, other tools such as SQL Developer, PL/SQL Developer and Toad emulate many SQL\*Plus features and so you may be used to `exec(ute)` in those as well, but it is not part of SQL or PL/SQL, so a multi-platform tool such as Datagrip can't be assumed to provide it.

Answer (score 3):

So don't `exec` it. Proper way to do that is

```
begin
  p2;
end;
/
```

anyway.

Answer (score 2):

In DataGrip any procedure can be run via context menu.

[image]